# easeljs in android 4.1.2 samsung phone bug?

Tags: android, canvas, html5-canvas, easeljs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/lib.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
    body{margin: 0;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="btn1" style="width: 200px; height: 100px;">隐藏</button>
    <button id="btn2" style="width: 200px; height: 100px;">显示</button>
    <div id="box" style="display none;">
        <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
    </div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    var _canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    _canvas.width = $(document).width();
    _canvas.height = $(document).height() - 150;

    _stage = new createjs.Stage(_canvas);
    var ss = new createjs.SpriteSheet({
        images: ["/app/resource/image/trick/animation/cow_basketball/ploughR.png", "/app/resource/image/trick/animation/cow_basketball/ploughL.png"],
        frames: {regX: 0, regY: 0, width: 374, height: 200, count: 8},
        animations: {right: [0, 3], left: [4, 7]}
    });
    var bitmap = new createjs.BitmapAnimation(ss);
    bitmap.x = 0;
    bitmap.y = 0;
    bitmap.scaleX = bitmap.scaleY = 1;
    ss.getAnimation("right").next = "right";
    ss.getAnimation("left").next = "left";
    bitmap.gotoAndPlay("right");
    _stage.addChild(bitmap);
    createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", _tick);
    createjs.Ticker.setFPS(10);
    var right = true;
    function _tick() {
        _stage.update();
        if(!!right) {
            bitmap.x = bitmap.x + 10;
        } else {
            bitmap.x = bitmap.x - 10;
        }
        if(bitmap.x > $(document).width()) {
            right = false;
            bitmap.gotoAndPlay("left");
        }
        if(bitmap.x < -bitmap.spriteSheet._frameWidth) {
            right = true;
            bitmap.gotoAndPlay("right");
        }
    };

    $("#btn1").on("click", function() {
        $("#box").hide();
    });
    $("#btn2").on("click", function() {
        $("#box").show();
    });
});
</script>
</html>
```

in this case with android samsung phone has some problem like below:
1.click btn1 to hide the div
2.then click btn2 to show the div(normally should be a dynamic picture)
but at this time the page has a static picture stay there more

so,my problem is how this bug appears and how to avoid this bug?

Comment: What do you mean static picture stay there more? Do you mean the picture shows, but it's always the same picture?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't look like it is easeljs-related, the only bug that I noticed in your code was:

```
<div id="box" style="display none;">
```

should be:

```
<div id="box" style="display: none;">
```

So you were missing a colon there, maybe that helps.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, But the bug is not caused by style="display: none" if delete the style of div, the bug still exist. the bug appears when show after hide.